# Cannot access /encrypt endpoint of PCF p-config-server service

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/spring-cloud-services-samples/cook and managed to install and run Config Server in PCF environment (*SERVICE: Config Server, PLAN: standard*).

I'm now trying to hit `/encrypt` endpoint of the `p-config-server` service, in order to encrypt new value. I'm following the instructions at http://docs.run.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/config-server/configuring-with-git.html#encryption-and-encrypted-values:

`TOKEN=$(curl -k ACCESS_TOKEN_URI -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET -d
grant_type=client_credentials | jq -r .access_token); curl -k -H
"Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json"
URI/encrypt -d 'VALUE'`

...but I always get:

`{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Access is denied"
}`

On the other side, if I try to get standard endpoint, to get config for an app, I'm able to retrieve JSON containing app properties. E.g.

`TOKEN=$(curl -k ACCESS_TOKEN_URI -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET -d
grant_type=client_credentials | jq -r .access_token); curl -k -H
"Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json"
URI/my-app/default`

... gives result like:

`{"name":"my-app","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":"bb6e64592ced731ebba272430291a595e0f14a77","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://github.com/some-user/config/my-app.yml","source":{"my-property.name":"Test123"}}]}`

Any idea why I can not access `/encrypt` endpoint? 
Thank you.

Btw, I'm executing the command in CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708, with installed `jq` (command-line JSON processor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer from CloundFoundry IT support. In my CF environment, "encrypt" endpoint should have a trailing slash (/). So it should be `...URI/encrypt/ -d 'VALUE'`. Maybe it helps someone.

One more hint I've got: There is a CF CLI plugin for the Spring-Cloud-Services which you could use for convenience.

https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-cli-plugin

```
cf install-plugin -r CF-Community "Spring Cloud Services"

cf help config-server-encrypt-value
```

Comment: I have the same problem and it's not the '/' in the end. How did installing the plugin you have mentioned help you?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Actually you need to hit cf env command first and take note of configuration values from that which for sample looks like below:

```
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "p-config-server": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "access_token_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.cf.wise.com/oauth/token",
     "client_id": "p-config-server-876cd13b-1564-4a9a-9d44-c7c8a6257b73",
     "client_secret": "rU7dMUw6bQjR",
     "uri": "https://config-86b38ce0-eed8-4c01-adb4-1a651a6178e2.apps.wise.com"
    },
[...]
```

and then use those values in your curl bash script. for example

```
TOKEN=$(curl -k https://config-86b38ce0-eed8-4c01-adb4-1a651a6178e2.apps.wise.com -u p-config-server-876cd13b-1564-4a9a-9d44-c7c8a6257b73:rU7dMUw6bQjR -d
grant_type=client_credentials | jq -r .access_token); curl -k -H
"Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json"
URI/ENDPOINT | jq
```

Basically following values are required:

ACCESS_TOKEN_URI with the value of credentials.access_token_uri

CLIENT_ID with the value of credentials.client_id
CLIENT_SECRET with the value of credentials.client_secret

URI with the value of credentials.uri

Replace ENDPOINT with the relevant endpoint:

application/profile to retrieve configuration from a Config Server service instance
eureka/apps to retrieve the registry from a Service Registry service instance

Then I think you will no more get access denied response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I took the values of `ACCESS_TOKEN_URI` and others by inspecting the env of the app to which the p-config-server service is attached.
I'm able to get `/application-name/profile` endpoint, but `/encrypt` endpoint gives me still "access_denied" error. 
I guess I'll have to try to get to the IT guys maintaining PCF environment.

Comment: @pra-jazz Hi, I'm getting the same "access_denied" error. I've checked the application/profile endpoint and got a result like {"name":"account","profiles":["profile"],"label":null,"version":"some number","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"our config-server-repo url/account.yml",***some services, "eureka.client.register-with-eureka":false}}]}  and I'm still not able to use encrypt endpoint.